# Linkerd dashboard not working in AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, aws-cloud9, linkerd

I am trying to install Linkerd to my AWS EKS Cluster.

All works fine but I can't access Linkerd dashboard..

My IDE is AWS Cloud9, and I followed the instructions.

1. `curl -sL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh`
2. `linkerd version`
3. `linkerd check --pre`
4. `linkerd install | kubectl apply -f -`
5. `linkerd check   -> **All Green**`
6. `linkerd viz install | kubectl apply -f -`
7. **`linkerd viz dashboard --port 33335 &`**

**Visit http://localhost:33335 in your browser to view the dashboard**

**When I visit http://localhost:33335 , it says `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`**

The tutorial shows the dashboard, but I can't …

Thank you.

Comment: What tutorial are you using?

Comment: https://linkerd.io/2.10/getting-started/ is the tutorial

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Cloud9 IDE, but I'd try running the dashboard command from the OS native terminal, just to eliminate that as a cause. The `linkerd viz dashboard` command is a `kubectl port-forward`, so there shouldn't be anything special going on there

Comment: Does your security group allow port 33335?

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here, I had the same issue as the OP.

The solution was to allow traffic on that port in the security group, the name should be something like that:

```
eksctl-<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>-cluster/ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup
```

You can create a new one if you want